# Can't remove Fragment from TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, adapter

I have TabLayout with ViewPager

[image]

On click close button, i try remove tab

```
closeIcon.setOnClickListener {
    tabLayout.removeTabAt(pos)
    fragments.removeAt(pos)
    fragmentsTitle.removeAt(pos)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Adapter code:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, private val tabLayout: TabLayout,
                           private val ctx: Context) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

    private val fragments = ArrayList<FileFragment>()
    private val fragmentsTitle = ArrayList<String>()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): FileFragment = fragments[position]

    override fun getCount(): Int = fragments.count()

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence = fragmentsTitle[position]

    fun addFragment(fragment: FileFragment, title: String) {
        fragments.add(fragment)
        fragmentsTitle.add(title)
    }
}
```

In MainActivity setup ViewPager:

```
private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager, tabLayout: TabLayout,
                               fragmentManager: FragmentManager, ctx: Context): ViewPagerAdapter {
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, tabLayout, ctx)
    viewPager.adapter = adapter
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    return adapter
}
```

But when i remove tab, my fragment is not removed. Also I can scroll to the previous fragment

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by overriding `getItemPosition()`

```
override fun getItemPosition(obj: Any): Int {
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE
}
```